# Can't solve this:

Tags: java, methods, java.util.scanner

I'm a beginner.....I cant seem to solve this problem involving multiple methods....the method using the scanner isn't doing anything

```
package bucky;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {
    public static void main(String args[]){

        input();
        for(int time=1;time<values[2];++time){

            double A=values[1]*Math.pow(1+values[3], time);

        System.out.println("You have: "+A+ " subscribers today");
        }}

        public static double[] input(){
            Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
            double[] values=new double[3];



            System.out.println("Enter the Principal value: ");
            values[1]=s.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter the no. of days: ");

            values[2]=s.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter the Rate of growth : ");
            values[3]=s.nextDouble();
            return values;
        }
}
```

Comment: Now, what exactly you want to do? Nothing clear from your question. Please check on how to ask questions.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: It doesn't compile. `values[]` is not accessible in main method

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please read [the welcome tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), it will help you getting better answers.

Comment: @Lucero The question was remove my errors.

Answer (score 2):

`input()` has to be assigned to `values` right? Like: `double[] values = input();`

Also, the indexing in array starts with 0... so values[0] is the first value and so on.

Try this code:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    double[] values = input();
    for (int time = 1; time < values[2]; ++time)
    {
        double A = values[1] * Math.pow(1 + values[3], time);

        System.out.println("You have: " + A + " subscribers today");
    }
}

public static double[] input()
{
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    double[] values = new double[3];

    System.out.println("Enter the Principal value: ");
    values[0] = s.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter the no. of days: ");

    values[1] = s.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the Rate of growth : ");
    values[2] = s.nextDouble();
    return values;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you can call the static method `input` like this? doesnt it need to be `test.input()` (test as the class he defined) or remove the static qualifier?

Comment: Yeap, you can call static method like that as long as it is in the same context (class). If you remove the qualifier then you'll need the instance of object to access the method.

Comment: Well, you are right. Might have done that without knowing. Thanks

Comment: already tried before asking.....error :Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field s
 Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field s
 Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field s

 at bucky.test.input(test.java:28)
 at bucky.test.main(test.java:10)

Comment: never mind....user218046....dude you are awesome....thanks man.....if you don't mind my asking, where did i go wrong.....thanks again

Comment: Well: 1) You've called method input() and haven't saved its returned values somewhere (to use in for loop); 2) because the main method is static it can directly call only the static methods from its body (he can't see non-static methods as they doesn't exist without their class object) and also it can call methods of objects who were created in its body: like... new Someone().input(); 3) when getting data from array the indexing of elements starts from 0... so myArr[0] is the first element, myArr[1] is the second and so on... until myArr[ myArr.length - 1 ] which is the last element.

Answer (score 0):

Try double[] values = input(); in main method.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test { public static void main(String args[])
{

    double[] values = input();
    for(int time=1;time<values[2];++time){

        double A=values[0]*Math.pow(1+values[2], time);

    System.out.println("You have: "+A+ " subscribers today");
    }}

    public static double[] input()
    {
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        double[] values=new double[3];



        System.out.println("Enter the Principal value: ");
        values[0]=s.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter the no. of days: ");

        values[1]=s.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the Rate of growth : ");
        values[2]=s.nextDouble();
        return values;
    }

}
```

Again it is going to throw an arrayoutofbondsexception...change `values[1]` with `values[0]` `values [2]` with `values[1]` and `values[3]` with `values[2]`..